How to set a cookie in asp.net and retrieve it in a Blazor web-assembly app?
I have a need to create a cookie in my API that I can then retrieve in my Blazor WebAssembly page.  The server side is creating the cookie which I have verified by using 'F12' in my browser where I see the cookie in the Application Page.  However, I cannot figure out how to retrieve it in the Blazor page.
Following is the code on the server:
namespace BlazorCookie.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class GetCookieController : ControllerBase
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            CookieOptions cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
            {
                Secure = true,
                Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                HttpOnly = true,
                IsEssential = true,
                Path = "/",
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
            };

            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("MyCookie", "ASDFJKL12345", cookieOptions);

            return "This is a fine kettle of fish with a cookie.";
        }
    }
}

And following is the code from my Blazor page:
@page "/getcookie"
<h3>GetCookie</h3>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="CallAPI">Get The Cookie</button>
<p>@someText</p>
@code {
    [Inject] HttpClient _http { get; set; }
    [Inject] IJSRuntime _jsRuntime { get; set; }

    string? someText { get; set; }
    private async Task CallAPI()
    {
        try
        {     
            //
            // Call the API that returns a response cookie named 'MyCookie'
            // We verified that it comes back by looking at the browser's developer page.
            //
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _http.GetAsync("api/getcookie");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            someText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            //
            // Try invoking a JS function to get "MyCookie" - this returns empty.
            //
            Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> moduleTask = new(() => _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/cookieUtil.js").AsTask());
            var module = await moduleTask.Value;
            var theValue = await module.InvokeAsync<string>("theCookieGetter", "MyCookie");            
            //
            // The js method did not work, so
            // look at the response headers - maybe the cookie is there?
            //
            foreach(var header in response.Headers)
            {
                foreach (var value in header.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"responseHeader: {header.Key}: {value}");
                }
            }
            //
            // No joy - how about the Request Message headers
            //
            foreach (var header in response.RequestMessage.Headers)
            {
                foreach (var value in header.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"requestHeader: {header.Key}: {value}");
                }
            }
            //
            // Nope, these are empty.
            //
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);    
        }
    }
}

I have searched a lot of questions, and I see some that refer to using CookieAuthentication, but I am not using that, I just need to set a cookie in my API and then display / use it in my Blazor page.
I have tried reading it from a JS function, but when I debug that function, document.cookie is empty.  Here is my JS code:
export async function theCookieGetter(cname) {
        let name = cname + "=";
        let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            let c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

Please help - this is a stand-alone example of the concept I am trying to get working in my app.
Thanks!
UPDATE
I have verified that the API is putting a "Set-Cookie" header in its response (as it should), and in the Blazor WebAssembly page, somehow it does set the cookie.  When I send a subsequent request to the API, I look at the cookies in the incoming request, and "MyCookie: is there, so I know that the Blazor client is properly setting it.
My issue is that on the Blazor client, I need to read the contents of that cookie, and so far I cannot get that accomplished.  I have added a header on the client "credentials" / "include" as per someone's suggestion, but I still cannot read the cookie value in my client app.
Any help is appreciated - this is Blazor WebAssembly, not Blazor Server.
if (!_http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("credentials"))
{
    _http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("credentials", "include");
}


See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63478620/creating-and-reading-cookies-on-blazor-server-side/64687687#64687687

I checked the above link, and tried putting my JS into index.html.  I get the same results - after the call to the API, the document.cookie is still empty. I also tried calling it in the OnAfterRenderAsync method when not the firstRender, and still no joy.  One suggestion was to inject the IHttpContextAccessor, but there is no HttpContext in a Blazor WebAssembly app - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71200755/blazor-wasm-ihttpcontextaccessor . When I look at the Application Tab in my F12 (DeveloperPage) I DO see the cookie. However, the Blazor app cant access it.
